# Reason(s) to play 5. Nf3 in the stonewall dutch opening?

Tags: opening, dutch-defense

I have heard that it is a good idea for white to trade dark-squared bishops because blacks pawns often end up on light squares leaving the dark squares vulnerable.  In the scenario below, it seems `5. Nh3` is white's best move for reasons I will explain below, but are there any good reasons why white would choose `5. Nf3` over `5. Nh3`

```
[FEN ""]
1. d4 f5 2. g3 Nf6 3. Bg2 e6 4. c4 d5 5. Nf3 (5. Nh3) c6
```

If white does in fact play `5. Nf3` and play continues with `5...c6 6. O-O Bd6`, then if white's Knight were on `h3` instead of `f3`, white could easily prepare the move `Bf4` without worrying about getting a damaged pawn structure.  With `5. Nf3 c6 6. O-O Bd6`, white's best move is `b3` aiming to exchange dark squared bishops with `Ba3`, but black's `Qd7` stops the dark squared bishop exchange for sometime.

Given the above, if white isntead decides to play `5. Nh3`, white is preparing `Bf4` for the exchange of the dark squared bishops and avoids the battery of the Bishop on `d6` and the Queen on `d7`.

Given that `5. Nh3` has known as long as the stonewall formation has been known and masters of the past have played it frequently, so why is `5. Nf3` more popular when it actually seems inferior to `5. Nh3`.  Is it because `5. Nf3` just seems like a more natural move or has a more natural feel to it?  Are there any other reasons to play `5. Nf3` over `5. Nh3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple thoughts:

1. After `Bxf4`, taking `gxf4` is acceptable.  The g-file is open, black's ideas of `g5` are prevented, you have a lock on e5, and can fix the pawn structure with `f3`+`e4`.
2. After a `g5-g4` push, h4 is often a better square for the knight than f4, to stop `h5-h4`.
3. `f3` points at e5, a better square than f4.  `f4` is vulnerable to an `e5` push, and the e6 pawn is rarely weak.